# Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combine reducers is an object whose values are reducers

Tags: android, react-native, redux, react-redux

When I am running my React Native code in android device I got the following error.

> "Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers."

Here are my authReducer.js and rootReducer.js
Please help me in resolving this issue. Also I am using redux-persist in this project. 
Thanks..

```
//authReducer.js

import { createReducer } from "reduxsauce";
import {
  LOG_IN_USER,
  LOG_IN_USER_SUCCESS,
  LOG_IN_USER_FAILURE
} from "../actions/Auth.actions";

export type AuthState = {
  authData: ?AuthData,
  isLoading: boolean,
  authError: any,
  isSigningOut: boolean,
  signoutError: any,
  isLoggingIn: boolean,
  loginError: any
};

export const INITIAL_STATE: AuthState = {
  authData: null,
  isLoading: false,
  authError: null,
  isSigningOut: false,
  signoutError: null,
  isLoggingIn: false,
  loginError: null
};

export const loginUser = (
  state: AuthState = INITIAL_STATE,
  { payload: UserLoginData }
): AuthState => {
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoggingIn: true
  };
};

export const loginUserSuccess = (
  state: AuthState = INITIAL_STATE,
  { payload: { data } }
): AuthState => {
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoggingIn: false,
    authData: data,
    loginError: null
  };
};

export const loginUserFailure = (
  state: AuthState = INITIAL_STATE,
  { payload: error }
): AuthState => {
  return {
    ...state,
    isLoggingIn: false,
    loginError: error
  };
};

const ACTION_HANDLERS = {
  [LOG_IN_USER]: loginUser,
  [LOG_IN_USER_SUCCESS]: loginUserSuccess,
  [LOG_IN_USER_FAILURE]: loginUserFailure
};

export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, ACTION_HANDLERS);

//rootReducer.js

import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

import authReducer from '../modules/auth/reducers/reducer'

export default rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer
})
```

Comment: Is your `authReducer` this one: `export default createReducer(INITIAL_STATE, ACTION_HANDLERS)` ? Did you create `LOG_IN_USER` & Co. with `createAction` or what kind of type are they?

Comment: I have used a library called reduxsauce. I have edited the code now you can identify authReducer.